# Hide content inside label

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with a wordpress plugin and I'm trying to hide (or even replace that would just be awesome) the words "DD", "MM" and "YYYY" in the following code:

```
<div class="smFormInlineFormCont">
    <div class="smInlineForm smInlineFormDate">
        <span>
        <label><input name="smFieldData[wpformfield5627][date][dd]" id="smform-field-yyyy2452" 
            value=""
            class="smFieldDD smform-control smform-field-sizelarge "
            type="number"  date-type="date"  min="1" max="31" /> DD</label></span>

        <span><label><input name="smFieldData[wpformfield5627][date][mm]" id="smform-field-mm2452" 
            value=""
            class="smFieldMM smform-control smform-field-sizelarge "
            type="number"  date-type="date"  min="1" max="12" /> MM</label></span>

        <span><label><input name="smFieldData[wpformfield5627][date][yyyy]" id="smform-field-yyyy2452" 
            value=""
            class="smFieldDD smform-control smform-field-sizelarge "
            type="number"  date-type="date" min="1" max="9999" /> YYYY</label></span>
    </div>
```

The thing is that I'm building a website in French so I'd rather put JJ, MM, AAAA instead or simply delete all together the letters which are bothering me.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why can't you just change the text?

Comment: @MichaelCoker It's a wordpress plugin so it's automatically added :/

Answer (score 0):

To replace texts you need using javascript or jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('label').each(function(){
     var txt = $(this).text().replace("YYYY", "AAAA").replace("DD", "JJ");
     var inp = $(this).find('input');
     $(this).html('');
     $(this).append(inp);
     $(this).append(txt);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="smFormInlineFormCont">
    <div class="smInlineForm smInlineFormDate">
        <span>
        <label><input name="smFieldData[wpformfield5627][date][dd]" id="smform-field-yyyy2452" 
            value=""
            class="smFieldDD smform-control smform-field-sizelarge "
            type="number"  date-type="date"  min="1" max="31" /> DD</label></span>

        <span><label><input name="smFieldData[wpformfield5627][date][mm]" id="smform-field-mm2452" 
            value=""
            class="smFieldMM smform-control smform-field-sizelarge "
            type="number"  date-type="date"  min="1" max="12" /> MM</label></span>

        <span><label><input name="smFieldData[wpformfield5627][date][yyyy]" id="smform-field-yyyy2452" 
            value=""
            class="smFieldDD smform-control smform-field-sizelarge "
            type="number"  date-type="date" min="1" max="9999" /> YYYY</label></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: looks nice thx! Is their a way to target the DD and YYYY inside <div class="smInlineForm smInlineFormDate"></div> ? I don't know JS yet :/

Comment: You can only paset the code between`<script> </script>` block in your code!. And I dont think there is a way to this with css only...